# Having trouble identifying a component

Tags: components

I'm trying to find a replacement for a little chip that appears to be melted a little bit. It's an 8-pin, surface-mount device. There are no visible manufacturer logos on it, but there are a few numbers, but Google-ing has rendered no results that I could find. It's the chip in the center of the photo, in case that's not clear. It's a little harder to read in the photo than in person, so these are the markings visible on the chip. Thanks for any assistance.
top: 3410G
middle: 2y
bottom: G1128
[image: board]

Comment: Does "caution static electricity" mean that the board generates static? or use ESD precautions? Whoever threw that message on there needs a lesson in communication

Comment: Don't assume replacing the one part will fix the problem. It's extremely rare for microelectronic parts to just fail for no reason. There's often something causing the problem that may still persist on the board (such as a short). Once you get a datasheet for that part, it's worth looking at it's function and doing a little detective work as to WHY that part failed.

Comment: Makes sense,  that was the only visible damage I could find, and a cursory inspection with my unaided eyeballs didn't reveal any blatant shorts, like a piece of metal laying between two traces or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That chip is a [BTS 3410G.](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BTS3410G-productbrief.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ed1d7b2011eff22f0da6bdf) Little power switch.

[This](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/BTS3410GXUMA1/BTS3410GXUMA1CT-ND/2231088) should be what you're looking for. Double check me on that to be sure.

Comment: Hot dog! That sure looks like it, how'd you figure that out? I'm not sure how I could be certain though, all I have to go on are the numbers written on it. I'm still pretty new to taking things apart that I shouldn't be in order to try fixing them.

Comment: You said you google'd it but didn't see anything. I'm not sure what you typed in but it was the first result when I did it. P/N's are usually the top number. So I tried that first. Glad to help.

Comment: So I just Google'd again, and I'm definitely getting different results than on my work computer. Or maybe I only searched combinations of the different lines. I can't remember anymore. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be a dual low-side smart power switch by Infineon. [BTS3410G](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS3410G-DS-v01_03-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46259d9a4bf015a84e190437573)

From what I can see of the layout it's consistent (eg. pins 1 and 3 tied together).

[image]